# UI Automation vs Backend Automation?

Tags: javascript, automation, phantomjs, casperjs, ui-automation

I have two columns of data displayed in the application. If a couple of entries of data missing in one column, I need to send an email notification to the operations team, data is not captured. How can I automate this monitoring? This has been monitored once a day manually and I would like to automate this. Can I read the browser screen and automate the notification or checking the database for missing entries and send the notification. I am a UI Person and like to achieve this automation using javascript. Can this be achievable via javascript or any other latest UI or testing frameworks.

[image: img]

Comment: Do this backend ( or frontend with a script if really needed, but that's way less stable ) Just use the same data you use to populate the UI. Avoid browser scraping ( reading the screen ) at all costs, reuse the data that created the page. With node.js and node mailer, this is only a couple of lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the values using `javascript` from a browser using automation. For example you can use [this](https://github.com/TestArmada/boilerplate-nightwatch) boilerplate. Then you can locate elements in browser, check if they are ok, if not you can send email.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/quick-start.html). But I think it would be easier to implement it on the backend if you have access.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need a browser to render HTML content if you are only interested about some specific data. you could simply write any utility in almost any language / framerwork with basic HTTP and HTML support, get the HTML content, parse the table(Hopefully it has a unique id) and if needed do the notification.

If it would make sense to do it directly in the backend instead, well, it depends on the question:

> Where the data gets lost?

***1. already in the backend?***

Then do it there - do not complicate your life. No need for html parsing, just simple db and / or business logic calls.

***2. you don't know exactly***

Then do it on the frontend as that is a stable analysis point.